# charSequences.toString() при реализации логера не работает Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Здраствуйте,
Я новичок в селениуме, прошу помочь разобраться с реализацией метода из логера. Перепробовал уже разные варианты, но результат тот же.

Создал класс имплементирующий интерфейс WebDriverEventListener
Переопределяя метод beforeChangeValueOf я написал так:

@Override

```
public void beforeChangeValueOf(WebElement webElement, WebDriver webDriver, CharSequence[] charSequences) {
```

System.out.println("Fill input " + webElement.getAttribute("id") + " with value " + charSequences.toString());
}

Однако при выполнении теста (в частности перед записью определённого значения в поле email) логгер пишет в консоль такое:

Fill input email with value [Ljava.lang.CharSequence;@1e2d654

Как сделать чтобы в консоль выводился реальный email адрес используемый в тесте, а не вот эти символы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это происходит, потому что вы у массива делаете `toString()`. Вам же необходимо использовать `Arrays.toString(charSequence)`

Comment: Хух, завтыкал)
Спасибо Андрей!